Laravel's ORM query using with() not working with paginate()
I am grabbing the related meetings with each Department, hence I would like to have a pagination for each meetings list. I currently have this in my Inertia Middleware to have it available in my frontend:
            'auth' => [
                'user' => $request->user(),
                'departments' => $request->user() 
                ? $request->user()->departments()
                    ->with(['meetings' => fn($query) => $query->paginate(10)]) // paginate meetings per department
                    ->get() 
                : [],
            ],


I am expeting a paginate object appended to each of the departments for its meetings, so i can use it in the front end. It is supposed to return something like this:
"departments": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "department": "Human Resources",
        "meetings": [
          { "id": 16, "title": "Junta de prueba", "start_date": "2024-12-09", "end_date": "2024-12-09" },
          { "id": 17, "title": "test", "start_date": "2024-12-09", "end_date": "2024-12-09" },
          ...
        ],
        "pagination": {
          "current_page": 1,
          "last_page": 2,
          "per_page": 10,
          "total": 15
        }
      }
    ]


you cannot eager load paginator instances

do you want to paginate meetings or departaments?

Try mapping the department variable and then paginate the and return the result.
'auth' => [
'user' => $request->user(),
'departments' => $request->user() 
    ? $request->user()->departments()
        ->with(['meetings' => function($query) {
            $query->paginate(10);
        }])
        ->get() 
        ->map(function($department) {
            $department->meetings = $department->meetings->paginate(10);
            return $department;
        })
    : [],
],


The problem here is with eager loading—you’re trying to use it in a way it wasn’t designed for :). Let me explain what’s happening behind the scenes with eager loading in Laravel.
When you use with for eager loading, Laravel does two things:

Fetch Parent Models
First, it runs a query to get all the parent models (in this case, departments):
SELECT * FROM departments WHERE user_id = ?;


Fetch Related Models with ids from all parent models
Then it runs another query to grab all the related models (meetings), but for all the parent models combined:
SELECT * FROM meetings WHERE department_id IN (1, 2, 3); -- 1,2,3 are obteined by using something like $ids = array_map(function ($d) { return $d->id; }, $departments);



This is efficient for loading all related meetings in one go. However, it doesn’t support pagination per department because Laravel is fetching everything in a single query for all the departments. Pagination requires limiting the query with something like:
SELECT * FROM meetings WHERE department_id = 1 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;

But eager loading can’t do this for each department individually—it fetches everything in bulk. That’s why what you’re trying to do isn’t possible with eager loading.

Solution 1: Paginate Manually Using map
Since eager loading doesn’t work for this use case, you can handle pagination manually for each department. Here’s how:
'auth' => [
    'user' => $request->user(),
    'departments' => $request->user()
        ? $request->user()->departments->map(function ($department) {
            $meetings = $department->meetings()->paginate(10); // Paginate meetings manually
            return [
                'id' => $department->id,
                'department' => $department->name,
                'meetings' => $meetings->items(),
                'pagination' => [
                    'current_page' => $meetings->currentPage(),
                    'last_page' => $meetings->lastPage(),
                    'per_page' => $meetings->perPage(),
                    'total' => $meetings->total(),
                ],
            ];
        })
        : [],
],

Now, each department gets its own paginated meetings list, along with pagination metadata.

But... Here's the Catch (N+1 Query Problem)
This solution works fine if you only have a few departments. But if you have a lot of departments, you’ll run into the N+1 query problem.
Here’s why:

1 Query: Fetch all departments:
SELECT * FROM departments WHERE user_id = ?;


N Queries: For each department, run a query to fetch its meetings:
SELECT * FROM meetings WHERE department_id = 1 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
SELECT * FROM meetings WHERE department_id = 2 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
SELECT * FROM meetings WHERE department_id = 3 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
...



So if you have 100 departments, you’ll run 101 queries. That’s fine for small datasets, but it’s going to hurt performance if you have a lot of departments.

Solution 2: Use SQL Window Functions (Avoid N+1)
If you have a lot of departments, you can optimize this by fetching the first 10 meetings for all departments in a single query using SQL window functions.
Here’s how it works:
SQL Query
WITH ranked_meetings AS (
    SELECT 
        m.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.department_id ORDER BY m.start_date ASC) AS rn
    FROM 
        meetings m
    WHERE 
        m.department_id IN (SELECT id FROM departments WHERE user_id = ?)
)
SELECT * FROM ranked_meetings WHERE rn <= 10;


What’s Happening:

ROW_NUMBER() assigns a rank to each meeting within its department, ordered by start_date.
rn <= 10 ensures we only get the first 10 meetings for each department.




Laravel Implementation for your case

Fetch Departments:
$departments = $request->user()->departments;


Fetch Meetings with SQL:
Use a raw query to get the top 10 meetings per department:
$rankedMeetings = DB::select("
    WITH ranked_meetings AS (
        SELECT 
            m.*, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.department_id ORDER BY m.start_date ASC) AS rn
        FROM 
            meetings m
        WHERE 
            m.department_id IN (SELECT id FROM departments WHERE user_id = ?)
    )
    SELECT * FROM ranked_meetings WHERE rn <= 10
", [$request->user()->id]);


Group Meetings by Department:
$meetingsByDepartment = collect($rankedMeetings)->groupBy('department_id');


Combine Results:
$departments = $departments->map(function ($department) use ($meetingsByDepartment) {
    return [
        'id' => $department->id,
        'department' => $department->name,
        'meetings' => $meetingsByDepartment[$department->id] ?? [],
    ];
});




Now it depends on whether you can afford n+1 query or not.
